# Recompile with -fPIC option, but the option is already in the makefile

Tags: makefile, recompile, fpic

I get this error when I do the make:

```
relocation R_X86_64_32 against `vtable for Torch::MemoryDataSet' can not be used 
when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

It says that I should recompile with the `-fPIC` option. I did that, adding 
the `-fPIC` option to `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS`, but I still get the same error. Is there any way to solve this? I have seen that this problem is related with the use of a 64-bit machine, and it is true that I am using one.

Comment: Is this an error from the linker or the compiler ? Did you clean all the object files before recompiling ?

Comment: Yes it is an error from the compiler and yes I clean all the objects and I still get the same error. Thank you.

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250608/passing-a-gcc-flag-through-makefile Should have checked yours before posting mine.

Comment: If you don't mind, please show the sequence of flags you used (if you can still find the original after 6 years :P) so that we know in future what to avoid...

Answer (score 12):

I had this problem quite a while back and if I remember correctly, the fix was moving the placement of -fPIC just after gcc in the command line.  Made absolutely no sense, and less so now, but as I remember, that fixed it.

Comment: this did work for me aswell... adding -fPIC directly after gcc in Makefile i.e CC=gcc -pthread -fPIC

Comment: I encountered the same problem.  moving "-fPIC"  to directly after the "gcc"  (as you wrote) worked for me as well.    Puzzling.

Comment: What were the other flags you used with `gcc`? @ashishsony your example doesn't quite show `-fPIC` directly after `gcc` though.

Comment: I can confirm this strange behaviour with `gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.6.4`

Comment: I had this issue, and it was caused by a library that I was linking against, which was not compiled with `-fPIC`. After adding `-fPIC` to that library's makefile, and recompiling it, linking worked fine. I know this is a different case, but noting for anyone who bumps into this.

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same problem, but it had an extra twist.  The answer by @clintm  solved it, but I thought I would describe my variation of the problem here for future reference...

Makefile on 32-bit machine:

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS= -O3 -Wall
...
...   
%.o:  %.c
    $(CXX)  $(CXXFLAGS)  -fpic  -c  $<      

libmylibrary.so: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) -shared -Wl,-soname,$@ -o $@   $(OBJECTS)
```

This compiled correctly.  But the same Makefile failed when I tried it on a 64-bit machine.  I changed "-fpic" to "-fPIC"  and it still failed.  I changed the  object rule to:

```
%.o:  %.c
    $(CXX)  -fPIC  $(CXXFLAGS)  -c  $<
```

and it still failed.

Finally, I placed "-fPIC"  in the actual compiler variable (so that now "-fPIC" appears in the rule for each object **and** the rule for the shared library):

```
CXX=g++  -fPIC
CXXFLAGS= -g -O3 -Wall
...
%.o:  %.c
        $(CXX)    $(CXXFLAGS)   -c      -o $@    $<   

libalglib.so: $(OBJECTS)
        $(CXX) -shared -Wl,-soname,$@  -o $@      $(OBJECTS)
```

And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have some makefile like:

```
CFLAGS = -g -Wall
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJECTS = ...

TARGET = libmyawesomelib.a

all: $(TARGET) main
```

just add the -fPIC flag like so:

```
$(TARGET): CFLAGS += -fPIC
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
        .
        .
        .
```

so on so forth with the rest of the makefile.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem cross-compiling with the android-ndk toolchain. I ended up having to use

```
CC="$CROSS/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -pie --sysroot=$SYSROOT"
```

Neither `-fPIC` nor `-fPIE` worked for me in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I was cross compiling shadowsocks-libev on a CentOS 7 machine, the same problem happened to me, it works perfectly on my laptop with

```
CC=mipsel-unknown-linux-uclibc-gcc CXX=mipsel-unknown-linux-uclibc-g++ AR=mipsel-unknown-linux-uclibc-ar RANLIB=mipsel-unknown-linux-uclibc-ranlib make SHARED=1 CFLAGS=-fPIC
```

but on travis ci, it did not work, I have to add -fPIC to CC and CXX in order to get it to work

```
CC="mipsel-unknown-linux-uclibc-gcc -fPIC" CXX="mipsel-unknown-linux-uclibc-g++ -fPIC" AR=mipsel-unknown-linux-uclibc-ar RANLIB=mipsel-unknown-linux-uclibc-ranlib make SHARED=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after I upgraded gcc.  I had one .o file (sqlite) that hadn't been cleaned by the Makefile and as a result I had this issue (assuming because it was compiled with an older version of gcc).  After removing that file and rebuilding this error went away.

Answer (score -1):

if the project you'd like to compile has a correct configure script use like this:

```
$ ./configure 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fPIC ....' --enable-some-thing
```

so the flag will be all the Makefile's rule ...

few days before i've need an elder ver. of VLC to compile on an x64 machine, it has a nice configure script ;-)