# Add compiler option without editing Makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I should compile a program written in C through a Makefile. I should insert into the Makefile, some option, for instance: `-O2, -march=i686`. How can I insert this option in the Makefile without writing into it?

Comment: Can we see what you have in your Makefile already?

Comment: It must be a generic Makefile

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250608/passing-a-gcc-flag-through-makefile

Answer (score 25):

You should use a macro like [CFLAGS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CFLAGS). Check out GNU GCC [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/make/Appending.html).

Something like this should work:

```
CFLAGS := $(CFLAGS) -O2 -march=i686
```

Or, if you prefer not to modify the makefile use:

```
make CFLAGS='-O2 -march=i686'
```

The other options will be picked up automatically though. See [overriding variables](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/make/make_9.html#SEC83).

Comment: Be aware that CFLAGS might be created from complex sub-macros.  You might be better off overriding one of the sub-macros.  If there isn't a contradictory option in CFLAGS, I often use '`make CC="gcc -O2 -march=i686"`' to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Where I work, we use the dedicated user-defined macros for just such a thing--ADDED_CFLAGS, ADDED_ASMFLAGS, ADDED_EXEFLAGS, ....

Comment: There are sometimes variables in the make file that allow you to add additional flags without overriding anything: e.g. `XCFLAGS`, `XLIBS`. Just look at the makefile.