# Suppress warnings when building with GNU make in command line

Tags: gnu-make, gnu, gcc-warning

Is there a way to suppress compiler warnings for GNU `make` and only show higher-order logs, i.e. [errors](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Make-Control-Functions)?

Apparently, this should be possible using `make -w` as described [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html). However, for my version of GNU make (4.1), the man file specifies this as printing the current directory:

> -w, --print-directory         Print the current directory.
>    -W FILE 
>                        Consider FILE to be infinitely new.

If possible, this should be disabled both for make-internal warnings (`$(warning ...)`) and compiler-level warnings by `gcc`.

Comment: You seem to mix up the build system (GNU make) with the actual compiler (eg. GCC or clang) which is the one likely to emit most warnings/errors and who does have a `-w` flag to suppress all warnings.

Comment: I should clarify: Is there a way to pass such a flag directly to the underlying `gcc` compiler, or do I have to really set all flags in the make file directly? I do not want to adjust the file itself only to temporarily disable some logs for single runs

Comment: It depends on the Makefile. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602927/add-compiler-option-without-editing-makefile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129391/append-to-gnu-make-variables-via-command-line), it is not possible to directly add flags for the compiler. Furthermore, adding to existing `CFLAGS` variables (`make CFLAGS+=-w`) does not work either in most cases, as it ignores the append part and simply redefines the variable in the command line.

A very easy solution to fix this is by creating an empty dummy variable (once) inside your makefile and then defining it in case you need it:

```
# Add empty variable to add flags over command line
CDBG +=
CFLAGS += $(CDBG)
```

Which you then simply use as follows:

```
make CDBG=-w
```

Answer (score 0):

as in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

just add -w in your building command to suppress warnings, for example

```
gcc -Wall -w -o program pgmEcho.c pgm.c pgm.h
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything useful over the accepted answer from 2018.

Comment: this is the simple and straight forward to suppress warnings , when compiling using command line !! , no need to create variable

Comment: Agree with @kingbode. The accepted answer adds unnecessary complexity when the simple flag is sufficient.