# ROOT install errors: recompile with -fPIC

Tags: makefile, root, fpic

I'm now trying to install the ROOT package available from

- http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/installing-root-source

After `./configure, make`; I got errors like below:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /share/lib/python2.6/config/libpython2.6.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/share/lib/python2.6/config/libpython2.6.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [lib/libPyROOT.so] Error 1
```

I really read a lot about this problem; seems it's caused by running 32-bit software on 64-bit machine and I need to re-configure with -fPIC. 
So I tried to run

`CFLAGS="-O3 -fPIC" ./configure`

or
According to [Passing a gcc flag through makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250608/passing-a-gcc-flag-through-makefile)
Add inside .`bashrc`, I add:

```
export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -fPIC"
export CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -fPIC"
```

However, none of them works!

This really drives me crazy....Only difference of my case with others is here I have problem with Python2.6, while others with other libraries...

Can anyone help me....

Answer (score 2):

The error tells you to recompile `libpython2.6.a` with `-fPIC`, not the software you install. Actually it means that you are trying to link a shared library against `libpython2.6.a` while you probably need to link it against `libpython2.6.so`. So the shared `-lpython2.6` is either not installed or not found. Fix that.