# Installation of R 3.5.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: r, ubuntu, installation, updating, ubuntu-18.04

**R 3.5.0** was released on April 25, 2018. I'm trying to install **R 3.5.0** on **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS**. I tried the following code

```
echo "deb http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu `lsb_release -sc`/" | sudo tee --append /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cran.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
sudo apt update
sudo apt install r-base

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
r-base is already the newest version (3.4.4-1ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Wonder how to get install **R 3.5.0** on **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS**.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50634298/786542

Comment: Try https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-18-04/ for the latest version of R

Answer (score 5):

You can always compile from source, if there is not a binary.
For compilation instructions you can see: https://www.r-bloggers.com/installing-r-on-ubuntu/

Comment: this is more appropriate as comment

Comment: Thanks! It's my first response on the site, I'll take your advice

Comment: +1 Even though it is a simple, it is correct to use an answer and not a comment. After all, compiling from source is a valid way of installing R.