# Getting the latest version of R with Linux Mint

Tags: r, linux

When I run `apt install r-base` it provides me with a slightly out-dated version of R.  When I tried to look up how to get a newer version, much of what I found did something to the file `/etc/apt/source.list`.  The content of this file is

```
#deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 18.3 _Sylvia_ - Release amd64 20171124]/ xenial contrib $
```

Most instructions suggest appending something like

```
deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/debian wheezy-cran3/
```

But none of the various suggestions I've read have worked--presumably either because they were for non-Mint distros or they were for outdated versions of Mint.  I tried taking something that I found, like

```
http://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/
```

and editing it with the codename that I found elsewhere which seems to be the most recent, hence making it

```
http://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/bin/linux/ubuntu sylvia/
```

But when I ran the update it couldn't find the repo, presumably because places that have Trusty don't necessarily have Sylvia--although maybe it didn't work for some other reason.  (And I notice the UK address which probably is bad for me to be using in America, but I don't really get how I'm supposed to find an address that will have the right files.)

Since I see a number of times when this question has been asked and solutions always seem to be short-lived, applying only so long as that particular version is hosted by that particular address and is the latest version--can I ask something where the answer might have a little more longevity:  In general, how do you find the right thing to add to your `/etc/apt/source.list` file to make this work?  How do you find the right repo source (same thing as a mirror?), the current codename, and so on?  (It would also be nice to have a generalized procedure for how to solve this, because I basically ran into the same problem on my old computer with a 32-bit architecture, and would like to have R running on that too without having to ask the question a second time--but presumably the specific thing and place I'll have to download for that is different.)

Comment: I'm not an expert on Mint, but I think it's usually based on Ubuntu? Googling tells me that Sylvia was based on Ubuntu 16.04, codename "xenial", so I think you would want "xenial" as the codename. No guarantees it owuld work perfectly though.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50135440/installing-r-3-5-0-with-enable-r-shlib/50634298#50634298

Comment: Huh, @Tung, though I had tried everything on this site including that one.  Guess not, it worked!

Comment: if you want the latest version of R on linux you could consider adding Michael Rutter's git repo directly as a trusted source. I know how to do it in ubuntu, not sure how to do in Mint. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/rrutter
sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Follow the advice at https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/ for Ubuntu xenial. Meanwhile R 3.5 for Ubuntu is also available from CRAN.

Comment: Check out Michael Rutter's personal package archives here: https://launchpad.net/~marutter . `rrutter` now has updated versions.