# Compiling R 3.5.1 from source, no libR.so

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, source code for R 3.5.1 and the following configure command

```
 ./configure --enable-R-shlib --with-tcltk --with-tcl-config=/usr/lib/tclConfig.sh --with-tk-config=/usr/lib/tkConfig.sh
```

It seems to configure, compile and install just fine.  However when I attempt to run RStudio it givs an error saying it can't find "libR.so".  Compiling previous versions of R produced a copy of libR.so that was installed but for some reason this version is not, so it does not get installed and RStudio complains.  Is there something missing or do I need to add something to the configure statement to get it to produce the libR.so file?

Comment: I assume you run `make` at some point after that? Can you also run `make R.so`?

Comment: Yes, sorry I did run make in that sequence.  I tried "make R.so", just returns "make *** No rule to make target 'R.so' " ?  The same goes for make libR.so.

Comment: Not sure if this would help but worth a try if you can't find any other solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/50634298/

Answer (score 8):

I found a solution, I had to reconfigure and recompile R, leaving off the specification for tcltk stuff.  For some reason, configuring with tcltk and "--enable-R-shlib" do not play nice together.  The combination that worked was, when compiling R from source

```
make clean
./configure --enable-R-shlib
make
sudo make install
```

And then RStudio Desktop 1.1.456, installed from the .deb, seems to find R fine and it all works.

Comment: To complete the answer, `--enable-R-shlib` flag is what actually enable the build of libR.so. See `./configure --help`.