# How to `--enable-R-shlib` after `yum install R` in centos 7?

Tags: r, rserve

Based on [this post](https://www.rforge.net/Rserve/doc.html),

> in R. Unix users, please note that R must have been configured with
> --enable-R-shlib in order to use Rserve.

I already `yum install R`,then, How to `--enable-R-shlib`?

Comment: I think you only need to do that if you compile R from source. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50634298/786542

Comment: @Tung, Why not add answer?