# Can't install devtools in R

Tags: r, installation, devtools

I'm trying to use a script that needs the devtools package in R. I already fail installing the package. As far as I understood, this is what I should do

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("hadley/devtools")
```

Just those two lines in a script result in the error

```
Warning in install.packages("devtools") :
   'lib = "/usr/local/R/3.0/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/R/library"' is not writable
Error in install.packages("devtools") : unable to install packages
Execution halted
```

So the library doesn't have the permission for me to install the package? I don't have Rstudio, the version I'm using R version 3.0

Comment: Try setting up your personal library folder wherever you have write permission
https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/3-3-r-startup.html#r-startup

Comment: Btw you need to update your R version because it's too old. Many packages might not support that version of R anymore. FYI the latest version is `3.5.1`. This might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/50634298/786542

Comment: So I just create a pathway within the script? Say 'lib = /home/xy/lib/' and write it within the script?

Comment: Try `.libPaths("/path/to/a/folder/")` (this folder should exist beforehand) then `install.packages("devtools")`. `install.packages()` defaults to the first folder in your library search path.

Note that if you only want to install packages with `devtools`, those installer functions are being removed and put into `remotes`, so install that instead. You use `remotes::install_github("Username/Packagename")`, and it also will install into the first folder in your library search path.

Comment: @Tung:  actually, the latest version is `3.5.3`, as of today.

Comment: @user2554330: looks like there isn't any significant change https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2019/thread.html

Comment: No, mostly just bug fixes.  But bug fixes are worth getting!

Comment: I tried your solution @DuckPyjamas so now there is progress but there still are some issues - I can't load the libgit2 library: 'Unable to find the libgit2 library on this system. Building 'git2r' using the bundled source of the libgit2 library.', sudo-apt won't work. I think because I'm working on a remote server (?) do you know whether there is a workaround?