# Set environment variable for setup.py script

Tags: python, c, gcc

I'm freezing my Python project with cx_Freeze into a folder with an executable. Now, when I move my folder with .exe file somewhere else and run my .exe, I get traceback messages. All of those messages are referring to files and directories from the time when I froze my project not to the current directories where I have copied my frozen project to. For example. I built my project in C:/myProject/ then I copy it to C:/Users/User/Desktop and get a traceback. Traceback says error in C:myProject/build/script.py, line 15 rather than C:/Users/User/Desktop/build/script.py, line 15

Does anyone know a solution to this problem? I was considering using gcc flags, tried the `-fPIC, -fPIE`, but those don't help. If anyone has ideas, I would appreciate your help!

Comment: @Olaf how is this an answer to my question? if you read the description of the flags, they sound very reasonable. And clearly, i dont know the right solution here (that is also why im asking the question here), so i have nothing else to do than to try and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks, but I do as I please, not at your command!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set environment variables for gcc compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39122043/set-environment-variables-for-gcc-compiler)

Comment: I suggest editing your original question rather than posting anew.